# I don't see tabs: JSON Raw Data Headers when running a FastAPI app from PyCharm

Tags: fastapi

I'm working thru the online cource [Full Web Apps with FastAPI](https://training.talkpython.fm/courses/details/full-html-web-applications-with-fastapi)

When I run a lecture's app, my output is:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

What must I configure to show the tabs:  Raw   Data   Headers

Regards,

Nols Smit

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with fastapi, the response is as expected. Those tabs you're trying to achieve are either a browser extension or built into the developer console of a browser, perhaps firefox?  There are a lot of ways to view json + raw data + headers in the browser, try this search https://www.google.com/search?q=json+raw+data+headers&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSrOeMxpzyAhXmF1kFHVPDDNsQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1421&bih=854#imgrc=MwB-jcL5GXSXAM

Anyway, you're not missing any functionality. Just need to use your browser tools!